# Cloud Foundry Service Broker endpoint not on root path

Tags: service, cloud-foundry

I am currently trying to write a service broker for cloud foundry. I was not sure how to properly caption my problem so I am going to add some more detail in the question. Let's assume my broker would be running on `http://example.org`. Normally that would mean that it has to respond on the endpoint `GET http://example.org/v2/catalog`. In my case it is not possible to respond to `/v2/catalog` on root level but it has to be on a lower level, more specifically `http://example.org/v1/internal/cf/v2/catalog`. There is no possibility to change that.

While working with the CLI I tried adding the broker using

`$ cf create-service-broker test-broker test test http://localhost:29090/v1/internal/cf`

The CLI returns me `http://localhost:29090/v1/internal/cf is not a valid URL` and I dont get any access on the server.

If I change the URL to anything with less than 2 path segments (for example `http://localhost:29090` or `http://localhost:29090/v1`) it "works" and I get an access on the server and the CLI prints the response from the server (of course saying it's not valid, since it returns a 403). Is there some kind of restriction on the depth of the path for cloud foundry? If so is there a way to get rid of that? Thanks for you help or hints and best regards, Yanick

Answer (score 0):

We're a part of the Cloudfoundry API team and we noticed this question on Stack Overflow. We tried to manually reproduce this error, but from our end it seems like the cli allows us access on the server even if the depth of the path is greater than 2 path segments. It gives us a 404 or 502. We see:

`$ cf create-service-broker test-broker test test http:///v1/internal/cf
Creating service broker test-broker as admin...
FAILED
Server error, status code: 502, error code: 10001, message: The service broker could not be reached: http://127.0.0.1:29090/v1/internal/cf/v2/catalog`

Looking into the code further, we didn't see anything regarding depth of path restrictions, both in the API and the CLI.

Could you try these requests again with CF_TRACE=true and post the text of the responses here? (i.e., `CF_TRACE=true cf create-service-broker test-broker test test http://localhost:29090/v1/internal/cf`)

Also, what version of CF are you using?

Best,

Jeff & Frank, CF CAPI Team